# PHP Json Array Data with Chartist

Tags: arrays, json, chartist.js

im try to create a chartist line graphic from json array.

```
 echo json_encode($json_data);
```

return

```
[{"labels": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27],
  "series":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,17,0,2,0,0]}]
```

my jquery

```
var url = "/appx/array.php"
   var resp = jQuery.parseJSON(
   jQuery.ajax({
       url: url, 
       async: false,
       dataType: 'json'
   }).responseText
);


var data = resp; // here i dont know how to do

/*var data = labels: ['1', '2', '3','4'], series: [[1, 3, 7, 12]] original data*/

new Chartist.Line("#teamCompletedWidget .ct-chart", data,options);
```

series has to be array of array

```
 series[[1,2,3]]
```

my php code

```
for($i=1; $i<=date("d"); $i++){

    $json_array['labels'][] = $i;

    $json_array['series'][] = intval($clicks[$i]);

 }
 echo json_encode($json_data);
```

returns

```
{"labels":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28],
  "series":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,57,5,17,0,2,0,0,0]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the json response and recompose it into the format that chartist is expecting:

```
//JSON returned:

var resp ='{"labels":  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28],"series":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,57,5,17,0,2,0,0,0]}';

var JSONObject = JSON.parse(resp);
console.log(JSONObject.labels);
//[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28]
console.log(JSONObject.series);
//[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 57, 5, 17, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0]

// In your particular case, your response becomes the JSONObject
// So you would use resp.labels and resp.series 

var data = {"labels":JSONObject.labels, "series":[JSONObject.series]};

// var data = {"labels":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27],"series":[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,17,0,2,0,0]]};


new Chartist.Line('#chart1', data);
```

Result:

[image]
Codepen: [Chartist JSON data format](http://codepen.io/k3no/pen/NRVgbo?editors=0010)

Comment: series has to be array of array series:[[0,2,4,5]];

Comment: Right, from your question I figured out you already had that covered, but not that the whole data should be inside and object.

Comment: There is my problem i m beginner and i cant figured how i can return my data right format. i will add more info to my question.